# Not able to delete office calendar using Ews api

Tags: exchangewebservices

Hi I am using EWS for deleting a Calendar. Below is my XML that i have used for the same. What my understanding is that calendars work as folders in EWS. So  have used delete folder api.

Error message:

> The `EwsId` is in `EwsLegacyId` format which is not supported by the Exchange version specified by your request. Please use the `ConvertId` method to convert from `EwsLegacyId` to `EwsId` format.

While on the same ID when I am calling list item then it is giving right output.

```xml
<soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <m:DeleteFolder DeleteType="HardDelete">
        <m:FolderIds>
            <t:FolderId Id="AQArAGdhdXJhdi5" />
        </m:FolderIds>
    </m:DeleteFolder>
</soap:Body>
```